# Texto sobreposto em imagem sempre visível

Tags: html

Existe uma imagem e um texto sobreposto a ela que nada mais é que uma opção para alterar a imagem.

No entanto se a cor desse texto for branca por exemplo e a imagem tiver tons muito claros este texto não poderá ser visto!

Se o texto for preto e a imagem tiver tons muito escuros o mesmo acontecerá.

Isso acontecerá pra qualquer cor de texto, basta que os tons da imagem sejam parecidos.

Existe alguma forma de conseguir evitar esse problema? Alguma forma de 'detectar' os tons da imagem e só depois disso setar a cor do texto?

Comment: Da uma lida nisso: http://thenewcode.com/1029/Automatic-Text-Contrast-with-CSS-Blend-Modes

Comment: Muito obrigado! é o que eu precisa ver, site com conteúdo muito bom também!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar um contraste automatico você pode usar o `mix-blend-mode: difference;`

```css
body {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
 color: #000;
 background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,#fff 49.9%,#000 50%);
}
h1 {
 font-size: 10vw;
  color: #fff;
 mix-blend-mode: difference; 
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Teste</h1>
</body>
```

segue o link com o exemplo utilizando imagem: [Exemplo imagem](http://thenewcode.com/1029/Automatic-Text-Contrast-with-CSS-Blend-Modes)